# Buying an iPhone 6S in the US, and using in Europe?

Tags: iphone, sim

Should I be worried when buying an iPhone 6S in the U.S., if I want to use it in Denmark, Europe? I will be buying it SIM-free.

Worried in the sense that the network might not be working (GSM/CDMA etc.).

Comment: Worried about what? The phone not working, no warranty in Europe, it getting confiscated when entering the country or something else altogether?

Comment: My apologies: The phone not working w.r.t. network, etc.

Comment: if it's sim free it'll work without any problems, you'll need to check if the iPhone is compatible with your carrier to be able to use 4G (LTE) : http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/ . Even if it's not compatible, you'll have 3G+ instead of 4G but the network will work fine in both cases